# Azure ADAL Integrated Security

Tags: azure-active-directory, adfs, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to get Integrated Security (via NTLM via ADFS) to work from the Azure ADAL .NET client (v2.19). Our ADFS server is running ADFS 3.0 with Forms and Windows Authentication enabled (as described here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/josrod/archive/2014/10/15/enabled-forms-based-authentication-in-adfs-3-0.aspx).

I currently have made the following attempt and get the following error:

```
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + UserPrincipal.Current.UserPrincipalName.Split('@')[1]), false);
var nativeClientId = "00000000-0f32-4c38-bdb9-4ea5bd732c69";
var token = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(Constants.ReportingApplicationUri, nativeClientId, new UserCredential()).Result;

System.AggregateException occurred
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
:line 68
  InnerException: 
       ErrorCode=federated_service_returned_error
       HResult=-2146233088
       Message=Federated service at https://ds1.mycorp.com/adfs/services/trust/2005/windowstransport returned error: The message with Action 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).
       Source=Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
       StatusCode=500
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.WsTrustRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
            at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenNonInteractiveHandler.<PreTokenRequest>d__4.MoveNext()
         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
            at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<RunAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
            at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenCommonAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
            at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
            at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
       InnerException: 
            HResult=-2146233079
            Message=The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
            Source=System
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                 at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
              --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.HttpWebRequestWrapper.<GetResponseSyncOrAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
              --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
                 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.WsTrustRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
            InnerException:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

v2.21 in ADAL has the fix to address this issue where integrated auth was incorrectly assumed to be WS-Trust1.3